# how to pipe pwd into pushd

Tags: bash

How can I pipe in the output of pwd to pushd so that I can use pushd on the current directory. I've tried

```
pwd | pushd
```

and lots of other combinations but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use:

```
pushd $PWD
```

(`$PWD` is maintained automatically by your shell.)

Or, if you really want an external `pwd`:

```
pushd $(/bin/pwd)
```

Answer (score 14):

```
pushd .
```

also works